# Are URI's a regular language?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

Do URI's, as defined in [rfc3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), form a regular language?

How can I tell?

There's a BNF grammar provided, but I don't know how to check that it has a unique representation of every URI, or that it describes a regular language.

Comment: The question cannot really be answered without a more concise description, but given the examples at the beginning of the document, it seems likely that URI's form a regular language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some checks you can perform for yourself:

- Is there any recursion in the rules?
  *No:* The language is finite, hence regular.
- Can the recursions all be written in the form of $A \to \alpha B$, with $\alpha$ a terminal string and $A$, $B$ non-terminals?
  *Yes:* The grammar is (or can be transformed into an equivalent) right-regular (one), hence the language is regular.

If there are constructs like $A \to \alpha B \beta$ or even $A \to \alpha A \beta B \gamma$, then you'll have to look more closely, and there's no easy way: deciding whether a context-free grammar generates a regular language is, in general, undecidable (cf. Greibach's theorem).
See [our reference questions](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions/843#843) for techniques for showing either direction.

Comment: In this case, the second point applies. However, particular URI schemes (not covered in RFC 3986) tend to impose syntactic restrictions of their own, and some of these may be non-regular (although I'm not aware of any).

Comment: @reinierpost I didn't check the whole document, thanks! (I'm rather certain that, in practice, there's a length limit so the language is finite no matter what...)

Comment: There is no limit in the specification. For instance, I have a CGI script that executes a Turing machine; the initial tape contents can be supplied as part of the URL. A specification of how this script works won't impose a maximum URL length. A specification of how its current implementation works (it's written in Perl) won't do that, either (Perl doesn't have a maximum string length). In practice, supplying URLs beyond a certain length won't work, but that length isn't fixed, it's implementation state dependent, and there is no need to put such a bound in the spec.

Comment: @reinierpost Ah, I was thinking only of the `subdomain. ... .domain.tld` part. Didn't read carefully enough! Thanks for clarifying. (Good thing I wrote my answer in a very general way. :>)